# What is the best way to solve $x$: constant = $(x+1)e^x$?

Tags: calculus

I'm an engineering student and my little brother sent me a question, but the annoying part is that I have been stuck for 30 mins now and just going in circles trying logarithmic laws and other to solve it. Very annoying.

The specific problem he had was: $5.4367 = (x+1)e^x$
Of course I could say that $2e$ is almost $5.4367$, but I want an exact expression/answer for $x$.

Thank you :D

Comment: Is $(x+1)$ part of the exponent?

Comment: No, sorry will make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x+1)e^x=c$$
$$(x+1)e^{x+1}=ce$$
$$x+1=W(ce)$$
With $W$ the [Lambert function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Thank you, probably was meant to do the 2e ≈ 5.4367 since I very much doubt he learnt about the Lamber function.

Comment: The solution can be approximated with the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method.

Answer (score 3):

There is no exact solution in terms of elementary functions. The answer can be expressed in terms of the Lambert W-function, but I doubt that is supposed to be known.

$$x=W_n\left(\frac{54367e}{10000}\right)-1\approx 1$$